# numpy debugging with pycharm / intellij very slow

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I use a numpy based library for which the first step is to vectorize an input element array. It takes 0.7 seconds with debugger off and 33 seconds with debugger on. For more complex operations a similar ratio still holds - and so low tens of seconds become many hundreds.

Based on other threads the "collect runtime type information" should be disabled for better performance. Well .. it already is.. so then what more can be done (if anything) ?

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue. I reported it to Jet Brains so there must be an issue registered somewhere, but I can't find it right now. I ended up using pdb instead.

Comment: @EnnoShioji  Thx for the heads up on pdb. I am using it. Primitive but essentially as fast as when  non-debugging.

Comment: @EnnoShioji  Feel free to make that comment an answer for me to award.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In latest version `2017.1` of Intellij a warning about using a `custom intellij cython extension` is displayed.   The command is displayed in the `console`:

```
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 "/Users/sboesch/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2017.1/python/helpers/pydev/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace
```

After having run this the `scientific python` debugging is faster.